# where do exponential and logarithmic functions intersect?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

If $0<a<1$, then the graphs of $y=a^x$ and $y=\log_a(x)$ intersect at some point $(t(a),t(a))$. Does this function $t(a)$ have any nice expression? How much do we know about this function, except that it is obviously increasing and stays between $0$ and $1$? It is a very natural question, so I guess people thought about it before.

EDIT: why do I think it is a natural question? When we teach students calculus, one way to introduce the $\log_a(x)$ function is as the inverse of $a^x=e^{x \ln a}$. And drawing the graphs of $a^x$ and $\log_a(x)$ for $0<a<1$ in one coordinate system pulls attention to their intersection point right away.

EDIT 2: Thanks to lhf and Wolfram Alpha, the graph of $a^x=\log_a(x)$ for $x,a$ between $0$ and $1$ can be seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+a%5Ex-log_a+x+%3D0+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1%2C+0%3Ca%3C1).

It shows that for $a<t(e^{-1})=e^{-e}\approx 0.065988$, we have THREE points of intersection of graphs $a^x$ and $\log_ax$ (see example of $a=0.03$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e6esd0642j0)). At $a=e^{-e}$, the two graphs are tangent to each other (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ec47944jscb)).

However, one of the points of intersection can be seen as the "principal branch", which I denoted $t(a)$ above. It looks like it has an inflection point at $a=e^{-1}\approx 0.367879$.

EDIT 3: Interestingly, the graphs of $a^x$ and $\log_a(x)$ do intersect for some values of $a>1$, namely, if $1<a<e^{1/e}\approx 1.44467$: [example for $a=1.3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e6ekcf4qglb).

Comment: @Vishal Did you read the inequality in the question?

Comment: In other words, you want to plot the fixed points of $\log_a \log_a x$.

Comment: "It is a very natural question." Fixed points and iterated exponentials in my experience do not occur together naturally. (Just saying.)

Comment: See a plot of $x-\log_y \log_y x =0 $ here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x-log_y+log_y+x+%3D0+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1%2C+0%3Cy%3C1

Comment: ^ The graph appears to indicate that there are always two fixed points for $0<a<1$ except at $a=e^{-1}$ where there is only one, interesting.

Comment: @lhf: Thanks for the graph! It turned out that for $a<t(e^{-1})=e^{-e}$ one has THREE points of intersection of $a^x$ and $\log_a(x)$!

Comment: @anon: it is the other way around: for every $x$ except $x=e^{-1}$ there are two values of $a$ such that $a^x=\log_a x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this turned out to be an easy one. Since $a^x$ and $\log_a(x)$ are inverse to each other, their point of intersection (if unique) lies on the line $y=x$, so in particular, that value of $x=t(a)$ will satisfy $x=a^x$. Therefore, $a=x^{1/x}$, and $t(a)$ is the inverse for this function on $[0,1]$. The function $y=x^{1/x}$ (see graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e16738u003n)) has maximum value $e^{1/e}$ at $x=e$, it approaches $1$ from above as $x\to\infty$. Thus the functions $a^x$ and $\log_a(x)$ have two intersection points when $1<a<e^{1/e}$, they touch each other at $x=a$ if $a=e^{1/e}$, and have no intersection points if $a>e^{1/e}$.

A "closed form formula" for $t(a)$ may be obtained through [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
Since $x=a^x$, one has: $$1=x/a^x=x\cdot e^{-x \ln a},$$ and $$-\ln a= -x \ln a \cdot e^{-x \ln a},$$which means that $$W(-\ln a)=-x\ln a,$$ so that $$x=\dfrac{W(-\ln a)}{-\ln a}.$$

A [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+%5BLambertW%28-log%28a%29%29%2F-log%28a%29%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) of this function shows that it does indeed look like the inverse to $a=x^{1/x}$ on $[0,1]$ (see the graph in the EDIT 2 part).

Another question remains: what is the formula for the two "non-principal" intersection points when $0<a<e^{-e}$?

Comment: (Full disclosure, I haven't absorbed your answer, but the following is almost *always* the right response to "Why did my use of the $W$ function not get all the solutions?".)  You have use the $0^{\text{th}}$ branch of the $W$ function.  The $-1$ branch is also real valued.  [plot of both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#/media/File:Lambert-w.svg)